# visual studio solution configuration rights

Tags: visual-studio-2010, security, tfs

I'm trying to find a solution to prevent my developpers team running the solution configuration "release" which contains the production settings. 
I just want to prevent careless error like "OMG, I was in Release configuration during my test, I delete all the database" or something like this...

We are working on Visual Studio 2010 with TFS. I was wondering if there is a right to use a specific type of solution configuration and not an other...

If you know an other way to be sure this kind of error will never append, I'll take it too! ^^

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't restrict access to the configuration - restrict access to the database. Your developers should not have access to delete the production database!

Comment: They can access to the production database because the connectionstring of production is in the solution. I don't see how I can protect it from my developpers...

Comment: First, don't put the real password into the config file! Require that the DBAs or Operations people make that one final change to the config file before it works in production.

Comment: To be sure I correctly understood : you suggest to put a wrong password in the connectionstring and then change it just when you explicitly need to use the production DB? It's so simple but I never thought about it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As John suggested, you should limit access to your production database first. Next, you could have your release configuration error out if a particular environment variable isn't defined. Just check for that environment variable before you zap the database.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Today, my production database has only two authorized accounts : the admin's one and the application's one. My developpers don't know anything about the admin account but they can acces to the database through the application, thanks the connection string! I'm sure I'm missing something because I don't understand how I can restrict the access to my team. Next, I don't understand the part about the release configuration error... Thanks